# What can I do after our iOS app has been removed?

Tags: ios, app-store

Performance - 2.3.1 & Business - 3.1.1
Your app contains hidden features that enable users to purchase content by means other than in-app purchase API.

For this reason, your app will be removed from sale on the App Store at this time.

---

Our app has been removed from App Store.After that we submitted a new version but it has been "waiting for review" for more than a month.What should we do to update our App?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PeA4G.png)

Comment: Contact them in resolution center or call support?

Answer (score 0):

From the rejection line it seems like your app is wrongly using any payment options rather using inApp purchase.

As per apple rules if you know we have to use inApp purchase option for non physical existence products. Like for ex : Earn coins, points etc.

So make sure you are using the payment options as per apple guidelines. If all things are checked & as per apple rules than try to submit it again by sending appeal to the apple review team.

So by that way you can give them more information about your product & get approval.

Hope it will helps.